# UIImageView touch method

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiimageview

I have a `UIImageView` and I would like to be able to add two methods to it. One for double tapping the top half and the other for double tapping the bottom half of the ImageView.

Currently the code is just an `Outlet` referencing an the `UIImageView`:

```swift
@IBOutlet weak var postImage: UIImageView!
```

Could anyone advise me of how to make this happen or at least point me in the correct direction?

Comment: Look into [UITapGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uitapgesturerecognizer_class/index.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use UITapGestureRecognizer (obj-c example, for Swift it's basically the same)

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapImageView:)];
[self.imageView addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
gestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
```

then you can handle tap position inside of the image view

```
- (void)tapImageView:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    CGPoint location = [recognizer locationInView:self.imageView];
    if ([self.imageView pointInside:location withEvent:nil]) {
        // tap is inside view bounds
        if (location.y < self.imageView.bounds.height/2) {
            // tap in upper half
        }
        else {
            // tap in lower half
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How would I go about this if my imageView is located in my `CustomCell.swift` class and the `UITapGestureRecognizer` is in my `ViewController.swift`

Comment: Could I get that first bit of code for the creation of the `UITapGestureRecognizer` in Swift?

Comment: something like this, probably. `let recognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:Selector("tapImageView:")); recognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2; imageView.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer);`

Answer (score 3):

1. Enable user interactions.

   self.postImage.userInteractionEnabled = true
2. Use [UITapGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uitapgesturerecognizer_class/index.html)
3. Detect tap location.
4. Enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways that came to my mind.

1. Make the image view as the public property of the cell class and add the gesture recogniser to it in the controller class itself.
2. Or, after creating the cell object, call a method with **self** as a parameter and add the gesture recogniser in that method whose target will the **self** object passed.

Comment: Honestly man you're a genius, I would have never thought of that.